Regex / JSON Schema pattern for a hex-encoded bitcoin compact size integer
I'm constructing a JSON Schema for an list array containing a hex-encoded bitcoin compact size integer (a. k. a.  variable length integer, sometimes var_int) followed by the number of bytes denoted by the compact-size-int
{
    "type":"array",
    "prefixItems": [
      {"title":"bitcoin_CSI","type":"string","pattern":"[0-9a-f]{2}|fd[0-9a-f]{4}|fe[0-9a-f]{8}|ff[0-9a-f]{16}"},
      {"title":"bitcoin_bytes","type":"string",pattern":"[0-9a-f]"}
    ]
}

At the moment my regex pattern [0-9a-f]{2}|fd[0-9a-f]{4}|fe[0-9a-f]{8}|ff[0-9a-f]{16} doesn't determine if the first byte is <=fc for the first option (where the length must be 2 hex chars). Is there a better way of doing this?

The better way is to program it than shooting with a regex at it. What's so difficult to also use [0-9a-e][0-9a-f]|f[0-9a-c] for your first byte? Also: you have one [ too often multiple times, just like you don't want to write JSON as an abbreviation (in uppercase). If an initial f is repeated, match it once and put the other alternations into their own group: [0-9a-e][0-9a-f]|f([0-9a-c]|d[0-9a-f]{4}|e[0-9a-f]{8}|f[0-9a-f]{16}) (and based on the context enclose all that into ^()$ as otherwise it matches anywhere).
